# WPF Trigger not working

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers

I am trying to use [`triggers`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.trigger.aspx) to modify the property of my control.I have a `RadioButton` and a `Border`, I want to modify the border `Background` when the 
`RadioButton` IsSelected. So here is my code:

```
<Border BorderBrush="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignDivider}">
     <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Erase_IsSelected}" Content="E">
         <RadioButton.Resources>
              <Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                  <Style.Triggers>
                       <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignSelection}" />
                       </Trigger>
                  </Style.Triggers>
              </Style>
         </RadioButton.Resources>
     </RadioButton>
</Border>
```

This seems don't work, how should I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: We need to know the structure of your control. Is it used as a `DataTemplate` or any other kind of a `Template`? and I can't see your `Border` being included in the code snippet.

Comment: @XAMlMAX I didn't use any Template. I have reedited my description.

Comment: If you want to change the `Background` of a `Border` then you should use `Style` for `Border` **NOT** `RadioButton`. Use `x:Name` for your Button's tag and reference it in your `Border`'s `Style`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `Style` for the `Border` that binds to the `IsChecked` property of the `RadioButton`:

```
<Border BorderBrush="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignDivider}">
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rb}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignSelection}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
    <RadioButton x:Name="rb" IsChecked="{Binding Erase_IsSelected}" Content="E" />
</Border>
```

A `RadioButton` style cannot change the property of a `Border`.

Comment: This set property `Style` twice which did not pass the compile

Answer (score -1):

Add the **OnChecked** event in your xaml:

```
<RadioButton Checked="Radiobutton_OnChecked" Content="E">
      <RadioButton.Resources>
          <Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
               <Style.Triggers>
                     <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                          <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignSelection}" />
                     </Trigger>
               </Style.Triggers>
          </Style>
      </RadioButton.Resources>
 </RadioButton>
```

this will create you a function in your .cs like this, where you can change the background:

```
private void Radiobutton_OnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton rdb = (RadioButton) sender;

    rdb.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
}
```